# How to convert a date_select hash into a Date object during custom validation in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to Rails, and Ruby in general. I'm currently working on a personal project where I have to check if a user is **at least 13 years of age** before allowing her/him to register. I'm using a custom validation method for this purpose, called `check_age_is_above_13`. The problem I'm having is that the `date_select` helper in my view splits the date into `dob(1i)`, `dob(2i)` and `dob(3i)`, and I am unable to figure out how to access these in the `User` model. My code is as follows:

Migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email, null: false
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :gender
      t.datetime :dob #date of birth
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The `User` model looks like the following. I'm following the code snippet found [here](http://www.springenwerk.com/2008/05/set-date-attribute-from-dateselect.html), although I must admit it is a bit..... out-*dated*:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #using Devise for Auth
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :trackable,
         :confirmable

  validates :gender, inclusion: { in: %w(female male unknown) }
  validate :check_age_is_above_13

  def check_age_is_above_13
    #The following raises "undefined local variable or method `params'" exception
    dob = Date.new params[:user]['dob(1i)'].to_i, params[:user]['dob(2i)'].to_i, params[:user]['dob(3i)'].to_i
    #Trying the below code raises a "TypeError, expected numeric" exception,
    #which is understandable, as "dob" does not exist in the params list
    if ((Date.today - dob) / 365.25).to_i < 13
      errors.add(:dob, "You must be at least 13 years old to register with us")
    end
  end
end
```

The parameter while POSTing the registration form looks like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
    "authenticity_token"=>"49w4ylxRIDyuRTDASW+vsuFL6Q3eeWcyokKrNXt9taM=",
    "user"=>{"email"=>"benny.lava@buffalax.org",
        "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
        "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
        "first_name"=>"Benny",
        "last_name"=>"Lava",
        "gender"=>"male",
        "location_id"=>"1",
        "dob(1i)"=>"2001",
        "dob(2i)"=>"8",
        "dob(3i)"=>"27"},
    "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

How do I access the `dob(Xi)` params in the model so that I can convert them into a `Date` object first, before performing the custom validation on it? I'm using Devise for user authentication and registration, if it makes any difference.

**EDIT**: And the view looks like this:

```
<h2>Sign Up</h2>
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :gender %><br/>
    <%= f.select :gender, options_for_select(%w[female male -]) %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :location_id %><br/>
    <%= f.select :location_id, options_for_select(Location.all.collect { |l| [l.name, l.id]}), {:include_blank => false} %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :dob, "Date of Birth" %><br/>
    <%= f.date_select :dob, {include_blank: false, start_year: Date.today.year - 100, end_year: Date.today.year - 13, default: {day: 31, month: 1, year: 1991}} %>
  </div>
  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: can you please show the form/view as well? and the controller would be good as well...

Comment: @user3334690 Added the view file. The controller does not have anything fancy just yet, it's a standard generated scaffold.

Comment: I can't remember what a freshly generated scaffold looks like...

Comment: Try giving like this `if ((Date.today - dob.to_date) / 365.25).to_i < 13`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to access `params` hash from a controller and view layers, but not from your model layer. Thus, trying to create a `Date` object in `User` model is a bit too late. Strictly speaking, you should already have `dob` filled up with a date at a controller stage, but if not, I would suggest you to override a `create` method of devise controller and set `dob` variable by hands there, just before validating `user`. Just for clarification, with omitting the devise overriding part, you need something like that:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # POST /resource/sign_up
  def create
    build_resource
    resource.dob = Date.new params[:user]['dob(1i)'].to_i, params[:user]['dob(2i)'].to_i, params[:user]['dob(3i)'].to_i
    if resource.save
      set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up
      sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      render_with_scope :new
    end
  end
end
```

After doing that, you should remove the `dob` assigning line from your `User` model validation method, as you have already got `dob` set up.

Take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kinopyo/2343176) containing tips on overriding devise controller if you don't know where to start.

Comment: Yes, your solution works perfectly! I had to override devise's `create` method in order to make it work. I'm still getting around to figuring out how devise works. That link you provided will be very valuable to me in the near future, as my app also has three types of users and it would be nice to redirect them to specific paths instead of `root_path`.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you probably shouldn't (and shouldn't need to) access params outside of a controller in rails.

Your model creation lifecycle should look something like this:

- get request for users/new
- users new method in controller
- serves the views/users/new page

user inputs fields then

- post request for users/new
- users create method in controller
- controller creates instance of user from params
- controller calls save
- save checks validations in user and returns true/false (true if saved, false if otherwise)
- controller redirects appropriately

Edit looks essentially the same except it uses edit and update methods in the controller and the model id is typically part of the url.

Anyway, if you are creating the instance of user appropriately in your controller, then in the validations you should be able to simply call self.dob (or even just dob) in order to access what should be the user's inputted date of birth.  Which because of your migration should appropriately be a Date of some kind.

In your controller, the users create method probably looks something like:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  if (@user.save)
    # respond/redirect
  else
    # respond/redirect
  end
end
```

As you can see the @user should have already been given those values from the params when it was created, so you should have access to them in your validations.

Comment: That's more or less what the scaffold user_controller.rb looks like. The `if...else` is surrounded by a `respond_to do |format| ... end` block. I reckon I should be doing something like `@user.dob = Date.new params[:user]['dob(1i)'].to_i, params[:user]['dob(2i)'].to_i, params[:user]['dob(3i)'].to_i` so that it'll be accessible in the custom validation method as a `Date` object. Both your answer and @twonegatives's answer work great, and I'm torn between which answer to accept! I need some more time to decide, I guess!

Comment: @Agent.Logic_ just a side-note that I just thought of... since you only need to see if the user is 13 years old or not why not do ((dob + 13.years) < Time.now) which basically is saying; was their 13th birthday before now?

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion! Coming to Ruby from a PHP background, I'm still thinking in the old school way, I guess. :P Everyday, I find out more and more that Ruby is really an expressive language.